# Skip the first level in JSON when using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

The JSON object I'm receiving is like this.

```
{  
   "Question279":{  
      "ID":"1",
      "Contents":"Some texts here",
      "User":"John",
      "Date":"2016-10-01"
}
```

I need to map the JSON to the following java bean.

```
public class Question {
    @JsonProperty("ID")
    private String id;

    @JsonProperty("Contents")
    private String contents;

    @JsonProperty("User")
    private String user;

    @JsonProperty("Date")
    private LocalDate date;

    //some getters and setters are skipped...
}
```

Also notice that the first level in the above JSON object `Question279` is not always the same, it depends on the parameter user provided to obtain the JSON. And I cannot change the situation.

Currently I'm using something like this.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = "{'Question279':{'ID':'1', 'Contents':'Some texts here', 'User':'John', 'Date':'2016-10-01'}"
Question question = mapper.readValue(json, Question.class);
```

But it's not working, of course, I got a `Question` class full of `null`. How to make it work in this case?

Comment: You can create a wrapper class around the Question pojo. Since wrapper class will have the Question as the data member, you can convert the json string to wrapper class and retrieve the inner object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON defines a map of collections, so you could parse it that way:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Question> questions = mapper.readValue(json,
    new TypeReference<Map<String, Question>>(){});
Question question = questions.get("Question279");
```

The `new TypeReference<Map<String, Question>>(){}` defines an anonymous class extending `TypeReference<Map<String, Question>>`. Its only purpose is to tell Jackson that it should parse the JSON as a map of String->Question pairs. After parsing the JSON, you'll need to extract the question that you want from the map.

Answer (score 4):

Try this can be any help

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

String json = "{\"Question279\":{\"ID\":\"1\", \"Contents\":\"Some texts here\", \"User\":\"John\", \"Date\":\"2016-10-01\"}}";

mapper.readTree( json ).fields().forEachRemaining( arg -> {

    Question question = mapper.convertValue( arg.getValue(), Question.class );

    System.out.println( question.getDate() );
} );
```

** As there is no default conversion from String to LocalDate I changed **LocalDate date** to **String date** in **Question.java**

Answer (score 3):

I recommend having your `ObjectMapper` create a specialized `ObjectReader` for each case:

```
String questionKey = "Question279"; // Generate based on parameter used to obtain the json
ObjectReader reader = mapper.reader().withRootName(questionKey).forType(Question.class);
Question q = reader.readValue(json);
... // Work with question instance
```